# How to unrar the STDIN?

Tags: linux, command-line, archiving, pipe, rar

What I have tried:

1. `cat archive.rar | unrar x -`
2. `cat archive.rar | unrar x /dev/stdin`
3. `cat archive.rar | 7z x -`
4. `cat archive.rar | 7z x -si`
5. `cat archive.rar | 7z l -si`

The `unrar` doesn't recognise the `-` filename altogether and says `Seek error in the file /dev/stdin` for `/dev/stdin`

`7z` complains `Error: : E_NOTIMPL`

So, is this possible? Any other tool to read the RAR archives from another program's STDOUT?

(Note: of course, the `cat` here is just for an example, the archive files can actually be retrieved with `wget` or something similar, but they are not local.)

Answer (score 4):

FIFO (first-in-first-out) streams like `/dev/stdin` are not seekable, and that's apparently what both `unrar` and `7z` needs to be able to process the files (unlike e.g. `tar` and `gzip` that both work with streams).

If using the RAR format and streaming from stdout are both important to you, I would first investigate whether the RAR format will work with streams at all.

Otherwise, for a workaround; you can make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/stdin > tmp.rar
unrar x tmp.rar
rm tmp.rar
```

And then run it like so: `cat archive.rar | ./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If your archive contains a video file, you can do the uncompression with VLC on the fly.
For example I managed to uncompress a rar archive trhough http:

```
vlc -I dummy http://www.example.com/archive.rar --sout="#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='file.mp4'}}"
```