# Unrar local files to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, rar

I have two Linux servers, one which has several RAR files and another empty one. I would like to extract the archives and move the content to Server 2.

The problem is: I do not have enough storage to extract the files at Server 1. Also I cannot use SSHFS, as no FUSE modules can be loaded on Server 1.

I have seen that `unrar` has the `p` option which sends the output to STDOUT. Is it somehow possible to use this to solve the problem?

Comment: Is this of any use to you? http://superuser.com/questions/708877/how-to-unrar-the-stdin

Comment: @Force: You can replace the `cat` from Nils answer with netcat. See `man 1 nc`.

Comment: You can copy the file to server2 and extract it there, ryt?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply log in on Server 2, and do

```
scp user@server1://path/to/file.rar . && unrar e file.rar && rm -f file.rar
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using only unrar and ssh.

You somehow need to mount a share from Server 2 on Server 1 and then unrar to the mount.
(maybe you can create a SMB,NFS or AFP share on Server 1, at least samba should be mountable without fuse)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and it **is possible** if you extract the files from the archive **one by one** (of course the destination cannot know when a file ends and a new one starts only using *stdin*)!

So if you can live with these limitations, do this:

```
 [source:/] # rar p -inul archive.rar filename | ssh user@remoteserver "cat > /path/to/destination/file.ext"
```

WARNING: The `-inul` parameter is **very important** because if you don't add it then *rar* will print messages in the destination file and break it.